# Is it possible to process JSON file from AlchemyAPI to generate questions?

Tags: java, android, nlp

https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/

I have my REST API and when I fetch the JSON file processed by the API and use it to create questions by removing the keyword on the sentence

{
      "sentence": "In 2009, Elliot Turner launched AlchemyAPI to process the written word, with all of its quirks and nuances, and got immediate traction.",
      "subject": {
        "text": "Elliot Turner",
        "entities": [
          {
            "type": "Person",
            "text": "Elliot Turner"
          }
        ],
        "keywords": [
          {
            "text": "Elliot Turner"
          }
        ]
      },

Thank you and hoping to get a reply thanks!